# Cannot update Manjaro Linux: Unknown trust with Archlinux-keyring

Tags: manjaro, pacman

I'm trying to update Manjaro but i have problems with signatures. The log shows this message:

```
error: archlinux-keyring: signature from "Erich Eckner (just to sign arch packages) <arch@eckner.net>" is unknown trust
```

A similar message appears with every package.

I tried with the commands of this troubleshooting ("Errors about Keys" section) but it don't works.

```
https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Pacman_troubleshooting
```

The time of my computer is corretly set, as I see with the command timedatectl.

```
$ timedatectl
                  Local time: mar 2018-04-24 11:42:17 -03
              Universal time: mar 2018-04-24 14:42:17 UTC
                    RTC time: mar 2018-04-24 14:42:16
                   Time zone: America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires (-03, -0300)
   System clock synchronized: yes
   systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
             RTC in local TZ: no
```

I tried refresh the keys of pacman and the mirrorlist, but the error persist. I don't know what could be the problem.

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171657/pacmans-always-failed-when-upgrading-unknown-trust

Comment: The answer of this post not works for me. The log of the commands "sudo pacman -S manjaro-keyring" and "sudo pacman -S archlinux-keyring" shows unknown trust error at install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue At Hand

You are reporting that you are unable to use Pacman as expected due to the following error:

```
error: archlinux-keyring: signature from "Erich Eckner (just to sign arch packages) <arch@eckner.net>" is unknown trust
```

As user GAD3R pointed out there are known fixes for this. However you report that they do not work. The cause of this is due to the fact that your key management has been messed up. You have gotten behind on updates or have something causing this issue.

## Fixing your Keyrings

I will be referencing several posts in this answer. You should read over them all in their entirety before making any fixes. The [linked post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171657/pacmans-always-failed-when-upgrading-unknown-trust?noredirect=1&lq=1) by GAD3R does work you just may need to take additional steps. One series of steps to take is [outlined here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/invalid-or-corrupted-package-pgp-signature/324/3) on the Manjaro forums. [Here is another possible fix](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/update-pacman-keyring-problem/21965/11) I found on the Manjaro Forums.

**First Try This**

```
sudo pacman -Scc
sudo pacman -Syyu
```

If that does not work you may need a more involved solution.

**Fixing the Keyrings**

According to user Chrysostomus on the Manjaro forums you should be able to fix your issue with these commands.

> ```
> sudo rm -r /etc/pacman.d/gnupg
> sudo pacman -Sy gnupg archlinux-keyring manjaro-keyring
> sudo pacman-key --init
> sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux manjaro 
> sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys 
> sudo pacman -Sc
> ```

Then attempt to run your update. Chrysostomus reports that if this does not work your packages may be corrupt. To fix this you may need to conduct a clean install with the [Manjaro ISO](https://manjaro.org/get-manjaro/).

**Alternate Fix**

Here is another way to potentially fix the issue from user stephane

> ```
> sudo pacman-mirrors 
> sudo pacman -Syy 
> sudo pacman -S archlinux-keyring manjaro-keyring 
> sudo pacman-key --init 
> sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux manjaro 
> sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys
> sudo pacman -Syu
> ```

Again, your issue might be out of date mirrors or stale or corrupt packages. You could try to fix this by making sure your mirrorlist is completely up to date before you install Manjaro from the latest update.

## Conclusion

You need to update your mirrors and keyrings. Potentially you will need to remove the existing keys. A possible explanation is that you fell in an awkward period between a release date and keyring updates. You may need wait for a newer ISO to be released and to reinstall your system with that ISO.

Please comment if you have any questions or issues with this answer. I appreciate feedback to correct any misconceptions and to improve my posts. I can update my answer if you let us know anymore details.

Best of Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried all the commands and my problem persists. Here is the log for "sudo pacman -S archlinux-keyring manjaro-keyring":`error: archlinux-keyring: signature from "Erich Eckner (just to sign arch packages) <arch@eckner.net>" is unknown trust`. I think the packages are not corrupted because I edited temporarily the pacman.conf for tests with "SigLevel = Never" and a "sudo pacman -S _package_ " command works fine.

Comment: How can I check if the mirrorlist is up to date?

Comment: Status of Manjaro mirrors can be seen at http://repo.manjaro.org/  Compare it with the mirrors in your mirrorlist to see if your preferred mirrors are up to date.

Comment: @JCMiguel, Have you attempted to update the mirrorlist of the latest Manjaro ISO and installed that? I would not recommend you continue using the `"SigLevel = Never"` configuration and just because some packages work does not mean all packages work. Clearly one tied to the gpg key that your system does not trust is not working.