# Unknown trust issue in Manjaro

Tags: manjaro, pacman

I have an issue similar to this issue: [Cannot update Manjaro Linux: Unknown trust with Archlinux-keyring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439780/cannot-update-manjaro-linux-unknown-trust-with-archlinux-keyring)

However, my problem is that I get unknown trust even with

```
sudo pacman -S manjaro-keyring
```

I've tried the fixes [here](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-solve-keyring-issues-in-manjaro/4020), but was not successful.

It may or may not be relevant, but my system crashed in the middle of downloading (but not installing) an update, which I restarted after rebooting.  That's when I noticed this problem.

Also, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439807/215701) posed that this could be a corrupt package somewhere, and would require a complete reinstall of Manjaro.  How do I determine that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to determine the root cause of this issue, and was forced to reinstall Manjaro.